# How to clear an element of canvas that is moving (leaves a streak) without clearing canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Say I have drawn a circle on a canvas that has something else drawn on it that stops me from clearing the canvas - due to the other element being randomly generated

```
var circleX = 50;
var circleY = 10;
var moveCircX = 2;
var moveCircY = 3;
function createCirc(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circleX, circleY, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();

}
function circMove(){
    circleY = (circleY + circMoveY)
//then validation to stop it from being drawn of the canvas
```

So what I'm trying to do is move the circle but clear the previous drawn circle from the canvas. So is there a solution to clearing the circle or would it be easier to create a sprite that replicates the circle?

Comment: Is the canvas background static or dynamic?  You said it's random, but once it's there, does it change?

Comment: It's static it doesn't change yet (it currently draws the grid randomly on the whole canvas but it doesn't change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your background isn't changing, the simplest strategy is to copy the background before you first draw your circle, then draw your circle.  When you're moving, redraw that part of the background from the copy you kept, then draw your circle in the new place.

An efficient way to do that is to use [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) and [putImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData).

So, (my javascript is rusty, so this may not be perfect.  Feel free to correct any mistakes), before the first time you `createCirc`, simply do:

```
imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
```

And, in your circMove function, before you move and redraw the circle, you want:

```
ctx.putImageData(imageData, circleX, circleY, circleX, circleY, 2*circle_radius, 2*circle_radius)
```

(You don't define `circle_radius`, but I'm sure you must have a similar value.  I'm using 2x the radius to presumably be the size of the image that is drawn.)

Comment: So if I were to animate the canvas (so it is dynamic) how would I go about redrawing the circle?

Comment: In that case, it's a non-issue.  Each frame, dynamically generate your canvas, then draw the circle over it. :-)